# Make SQL Select same row multiple times

Tags: sql, select

I need to test my mail server. How can I make a Select statement 
that selects say ID=5469 a thousand times.

Comment: MS Access ... using System.OleDb :)

Comment: Can you use Excel for creating a query? Are you trying to build 1 time query or you need to VBA Subroutine or function?

Answer (score 23):

If I get your meaning then a very simple way is to cross join on a derived query on a table with more than 1000 rows in it and put a top 1000 on that. This would duplicate your results 1000 times.

EDIT: As an example (This is MSSQL, I don't know if Access is much different)

```
SELECT
    MyTable.*
FROM
    MyTable
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP 1000
        *
    FROM
        sysobjects
) [BigTable]
WHERE
    MyTable.ID = 1234
```

Comment: Can we set a variable instead of setting an exact number? For example `...Select top @i from ...` Because I have a query which have a column named `number`, I want to repeat that row in `number` column times. for example if i have a row which its number column is 2 then it would repeat that column for two times and continue doing this for all of the rows.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the UNION ALL statement.

Try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID = 5469
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID = 5469
```

You'd have to repeat the SELECT statement a bunch of times but you could write a bit of VB code in Access to create a dynamic SQL statement and then execute it.  Not pretty but it should work.

Comment: wow! `UNION ALL`x1000 -- doubt that Access can ever handle such query =)

Answer (score 4):

Create a helper table for this purpose:
  `JUST_NUMBER(NUM INT primary key)`
Insert (with the help of some (VB) script) numbers from 1 to N. Then execute this unjoined query:

```
SELECT  MYTABLE.*
FROM    MYTABLE,
        JUST_NUMBER
WHERE   MYTABLE.ID = 5469 
    AND JUST_NUMBER.NUM <= 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of using a recursive common table expression to generate some empty rows, then to cross join them back onto your desired row:

```
declare @myData table (val int) ;
insert @myData values (666),(888),(777) --some dummy data

;with cte as
(
    select 100 as a
    union all
    select a-1 from cte where a>0 
        --generate 100 rows, the max recursion depth

)
,someRows as
(
select top 1000 0 a from cte,cte x1,cte x2 
       --xjoin the hundred rows a few times
       --to generate 1030301 rows, then select top n rows
)
select m.* from @myData m,someRows where m.val=666
```

substitute `@myData` for your real table, and alter the final predicate to suit.

Answer (score 2):

easy way...

This exists only one row into the DB

```
sku = 52 , description = Skullcandy Inkd Green ,price = 50,00
```

Try to relate another table in which has no constraint key to the main table

Original Query

```
SELECT  Prod_SKU , Prod_Descr , Prod_Price FROM  dbo.TB_Prod WHERE Prod_SKU = N'52'
```

The Functional Query ...adding a not related table called 'dbo.TB_Labels'

```
SELECT TOP ('times')  Prod_SKU , Prod_Descr , Prod_Price FROM  dbo.TB_Prod,dbo.TB_Labels WHERE Prod_SKU = N'52'
```

Answer (score 2):

In postgres there is a nice function called generate_series. So in **postgreSQL** it is as simple as:

```
select information from test_table, generate_series(1, 1000) where id = 5469
```

In this way, the query is executed 1000 times.

Example for postgreSQL:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"; --To be able to use function uuid_generate_v4()

--Create a test table
create table test_table (
   id serial not null,
   uid UUID NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT uid_pk PRIMARY KEY(id));

-- Insert 10000 rows
insert into test_table (uid) 
select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1, 10000);

-- Read the data from id=5469 one thousand times
select id, uid, uuid_generate_v4() from test_table, generate_series(1, 1000) where id = 5469;
```

As you can see in the result below, the data from uid is read 1000 times as confirmed by the generation of a new uuid at every new row.

```
 id  |uid                                   |uuid_generate_v4
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"5630cd0d-ee47-4d92-9ee3-b373ec04756f"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"ed44b9cb-c57f-4a5b-ac9a-55bd57459c02"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"3428b3e3-3bb2-4e41-b2ca-baa3243024d9"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"7c8faf33-b30c-4bfa-96c8-1313a4f6ce7c"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"b589fd8a-fec2-4971-95e1-283a31443d73"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"8b9ab121-caa4-4015-83f5-0c2911a58640"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"7ef63128-b17c-4188-8056-c99035e16c11"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"5bdc7425-e14c-4c85-a25e-d99b27ae8b9f"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"9bbd260b-8b83-4fa5-9104-6fc3495f68f3"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"c1f759e1-c673-41ef-b009-51fed587353c"
 5469|"10791df5-ab72-43b6-b0a5-6b128518e5ee"|"4a70bf2b-ddf5-4c42-9789-5e48e2aec441"
```

Of course other DBs won't necessarily have the same function but it could be done:

See [here](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/sql_server_blog/86/generate_series-for-sql-server-2008).

Answer (score 1):

If your are doing this in sql Server

```
declare @cnt int
set @cnt = 0

while @cnt < 1000
begin
    select '12345'
    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
```

`select '12345'` can be any expression

Comment: This returns "N" result sets with one row each, not a result set with "N" times the same row.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tmp1 (id int, fld varchar(max))
insert into #tmp1 (id, fld) 
values (1,'hello!'),(2,'world'),(3,'nice day!')

select * from #tmp1
go

select * from #tmp1 where id=3
go 1000

drop table #tmp1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Repeat rows based on column value of TestTable. First run the Create table and insert statement, then run the following query for the desired result.
This may be another solution:**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
 Col1 varchar(10),
 Repeats INT
)

INSERT INTO TESTTABLE
VALUES ('A',2), ('B',4),('C',1),('D',0)

WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Repeats)+1 FROM TestTable) rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns 
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT * FROM x
CROSS JOIN TestTable AS d
WHERE x.rn <= d.Repeats 
ORDER BY Col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This trick helped me in my requirement.**

here, **PRODUCTDETAILS** is my Datatable
and **orderid** is my column.

```
declare @Req_Rows int = 12

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1 FROM cte WHERE Number < @Req_Rows
) 

SELECT PRODUCTDETAILS.* 

FROM cte, PRODUCTDETAILS 
WHERE PRODUCTDETAILS.orderid = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked very fancy and simple method [from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39211939), that came out useful for me.

Here, simplified, we got cartesian product of 10 initial rows eight times

```
WITH E1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))     AS t(N))
    ,E2 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E1 AS a, E1 AS b)
    ,E4 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E2 AS a, E2 AS b)
    ,E8 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM E4 AS a, E4 AS b)
SELECT 'some value'
FROM E8 AS cte
```

As your understand, you can get any multiplication result by CTE, e.g. 14:

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))     AS t(N))
    ,T2 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1)) as t(N))
    ,T3 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM T1 a, T2 b)
SELECT 'some value'
FROM T3 AS cte
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use a heirarchical sub-query and a cross join: -

```
select     *
from       MyTable m
cross join (select level from dual connect by level <= 1000)
where      m.column = 1234
```

Answer (score -1):

in sql server try:

```
print 'wow'
go 5
```

output:

```
Beginning execution loop
wow
wow
wow
wow
wow
Batch execution completed 5 times.
```

Comment: Will this give a result set with 1000 rows?

Comment: @spender, would you like to see the sample output 1000 times? or is 5 enough?? if you can't see that it does it 5 times and the sample output has it 5 times, then you need a lot of help.  Op never says they want a result set with a 1000 rows, OP says they are testing and need a `Select statement that selects say ID=5469 a thousand times.`  one select of 1000 rows is quite a different test than a single select 1000 times.

Comment: I just suspect that this isn't what OP was asking. As far as I understand, they want a result set with 1000x the same row. Printing a value x times isn't equivalent. I see that we have a differing interpreation of what was asked, that's all.

Comment: @spender, you can replace the `PRINT` with any statement, `SELECT` generates multiple output lines (heading, data, rows affected) and uses more page space, so I opted for `PRINT`.

Comment: I did not know this syntax exists so definitely I learn new thing but I also learned this is an individual inserts and not batch inserts.

Answer (score -2):

The easy way is to create a table with 1000 rows. Let's call it `BigTable`. Then you would query for the data you want and join it with the big table, like this:

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable, BigTable
WHERE MyTable.ID = 5469
```