# Repeat chunk of data got from select statement multiple times

Tags: sql, repeat

1)I have the following query

```
select CRESTACode,Latitude,Longitude   from airgeography..tgeography where countryname in (
'St. Maarten') and crestacode is not Null
```

Result:

```
CRESTACode  Latitude    Longitude
6           18.035187    -63.076599
```

How do I repeat this data multiple times to get 3000 rows of same data in a table ?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: SQL , I am doing this in SSMS

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472662/make-sql-select-same-row-multiple-times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although it could be expensive:

```
DECLARE @InsertNum INT 
SET @insertnum = 3000

select CRESTACode,Latitude,Longitude   
INTO #tablex
from airgeography..tgeography 
where countryname in ('St. Maarten') 
  and crestacode is not Null 

WHILE (@InsertNum <> 0 )
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO #Tablex 
        SELECT CRESTACode,Latitude,Longitude 
        FROM Tablex;

        SET @insertNum = @InserTNum - 1
        Print @InsertNum
    END 

SELECT * FROM #tablex
```