# Break into multiple rows based on date range of a single row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which captures appointments, some are single day appointments and some are multi day appointments, so the data looks like

```
AppointmentId   StartDate   EndDate
9               2017-04-12  2017-04-12
10              2017-05-01  2017-05-03
11              2017-06-01  2017-06-01
```

I want to split the multi day appointment as single days, so the result I am trying to achieve is like

```
AppointmentId   StartDate   EndDate
9               2017-04-12  2017-04-12
10              2017-05-01  2017-05-01
10              2017-05-02  2017-05-02
10              2017-05-03  2017-05-03
11              2017-06-01  2017-06-01
```

So I have split the appointment id 10 into multiple rows. I checked a few other questions like
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211305/insert-all-dates-between-a-date-range-in-a-table-with-other-data/) but those are to split just based on a single start date and end date and not based on table data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can use it inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20161229'; 
declare @thrudate date = '20170103';
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select [Date]
from dates;
```

---

Use either like so:

```
select 
    t.AppointmentId
  , StartDate = d.date
  , EndDate = d.date
from dates d
  inner join appointments t
    on d.date >= t.StartDate
   and d.date <= t.EndDate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TNWQ64342

returns:

```
+---------------+------------+------------+
| AppointmentId | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+---------------+------------+------------+
|             9 | 2017-04-12 | 2017-04-12 |
|            10 | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-01 |
|            10 | 2017-05-02 | 2017-05-02 |
|            10 | 2017-05-03 | 2017-05-03 |
|            11 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 |
+---------------+------------+------------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [tsql Function to Determine Holidays in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_table_date - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=61519)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Nice! I've only met him once at one of his sessions at PASS.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly a Calendar/Tally table would be the way to go as SqlZim illustrated (+1), however you can use an ad-hoc tally table with a CROSS APPLY.

**Example**

```
Select A.AppointmentId   
      ,StartDate = B.D  
      ,EndDate   = B.D
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DD,A.StartDate,A.EndDate)+1) D=DateAdd(DD,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),A.StartDate) 
                 From  master..spt_values
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
AppointmentId   StartDate   EndDate
9               2017-04-12  2017-04-12
10              2017-05-01  2017-05-01
10              2017-05-02  2017-05-02
10              2017-05-03  2017-05-03
11              2017-06-01  2017-06-01
```